# Looking for Licensing SDKs for Flutter/Dart Desktop Apps

Tags: flutter, dart, licensing

My company is developing a Flutter/Dart set of apps for desktops, we are looking for a licensing SDK that will work cross platform, that can disable features or control trials. It should be able to work in an offline environment.